# How to sort week end date in the date table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI, having below date table

[image]

Created Week end date using below dax measure

```
Week End Date = 'Date'[Date] - WEEKDAY('Date'[Date],2) + 7
```

Can anyone advise the following?

1. How to sort the week end date? I created bar graph week end date vs Total hrs(which comes from other table) and it's working. However, axis week end data is not in proper order

[image]

2. How to format week end date into "MM/dd/YYYY" (Currently in "dd/MM/yyyy")

Sorry if this question is too basic. I tried various posts but no luck.

Comment: Please check [why should I not upload the images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors): if possible, copy the data and paste it into a code fence.

Comment: @medium-dimensionalsorry , my date table is big, hence unable to copy here.

Comment: No worries. In such cases, while asking a question, one can post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

1. You cut your bar chart screenshot exactly on the ellipsis menu (...) in the upper right corner. This is usually the place to go and change the sort order of your x-axis. (Maybe your data doesn't allow this, but then you would need to post some sample data - no screenshot - as already requested above.)
2. To change the format to "MM/dd/YYYY" use

```
End of Week US = FORMAT('Table'[End Of Week], "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Didn't my answer solve your problem?